# Getting strings within a getline string

Tags: c++, string, getline

Is there a way to traverse a getline string with a normal string.

```
string nextLine;

getline(fin, nextLine);

nextLine = "2 BIRTH OCT 30 1998";

string stringTraverse = ?;
```

stringTraverse needs to be "2", then "BIRTH", until all the words are read.

Comment: std::getline has nothing to do with this. Especially since you _immediately overwrite_ the string you just retrieved from "fin" (whatever that is). The second line is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sscanf on nextLine.c_str() to get each piece. Alternatively put nextLine into a string stream and then read until the stream is done so

```
stringstream s(nextLine);
while (s >> some_string)
    //do stuff with string piece
```

Comment: Why not just `stringstream s(nextLine);`?

Comment: @Kerrek, thanks for pointing that out, not sure why I did it that way

Answer (score 0):

Following is a pseudo logic (not tested, but should look like that):

```
size_t word = 0, currentSpace;
while(string::npos != (currentSpace = nextLine.find(" ")))
{
  stringTraverse = nextLine.substr(word, currentSpace);
  while(nextLine[++currentSpace] == " ");
  word = currentSpace;
  // ... use it
}
if(nextLine[word] != 0)
  stringTraverse = nextLine.substr(word);
```